# How to access message request in gRPC interceptor?

Tags: java, rpc, interceptor, grpc

I'd like to user the same interceptor on server side for multiple methods
as all of them have the same request type (`StateRequest`):

```
rpc apply (StateRequest) returns (StateResponse) {} 
rpc cancel (StateRequest) returns (StateResponse) {}
rpc remove (StateRequest) returns (StateResponse) {}
rpc development (StateRequest) returns (StateResponse) {}
rpc implement (StateRequest) returns (StateResponse) {}
rpc draft (StateRequest) returns (StateResponse) {}
```

interceptor:

```
public class ServerUserRoleAuthInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
        ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
        Metadata headers,
        ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        String callName = call.getMethodDescriptor().getFullMethodName();
        logger.info("Call: {}", callName);

        // TODO: validate request (`StateRequest` instance)

        return next.startCall(call, headers);
    }
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to observe the `onMessage(ReqT)` call-back on the `Listener`.

```
return new SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(next.startCall(call, headers)) {
  @Override 
  public void onMessage(ReqT request) {
    // TODO:validate request
    super.onMessage(request);
  }
};
```

Comment: `public void onMessage(ReqT message)` - it can't throw exceptions. Do i have to throw RuntimeException only (let's say `StatusRuntimeException`?)

Comment: You should not throw within an interceptor. Instead, call `serverCall.close(...)`.

Comment: `next.startCall()` will be invoked before `onMessage()`. Any chance to have it invoked `onMessage()` first as i need to adjust context dependent on message content before next interceptor starts to work?

Comment: @4ntoine, you can't choose the inbound callback order. But you can delay calling `next` until after you've received `onMessage()`.

Comment: how can i delay `next`? The next interceptor has it's own logic in `interceptCall()` and it's invoked instantly.

Comment: Simply save `next` somewhere and call it when appropriate.

Comment: I am trying to do a very similar thing now. Basically, I have two interceptors I am calling like `ServerInterceptors.intercept(new grpcResource(obj), new InterceptorA(),  new InterceptorB())` 

Where I want InterceptorB to run first, and during `onMessage()` read a token from the payload and set it as a header, then run the code in InterceptorA which authenticates the request based on that token. Using this pattern I don't quite understand how I should save `next` and then call it when appropriate?

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this, I have answered the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68164315/access-message-request-in-first-grpc-interceptor-before-headers-in-second-grpc-i

Comment: Trying to understand the some implications of these various approaches:
1. If overriding `onMessage` without delaying, the other interceptors will proceed, but the call handler won't be run before the listener's `onMessage` right? e.g. if we wanted to prevent the call from proceeding if the message contained some invalid value would it be safe to do this way?

2. If delaying `next`, what sort of performance issues might we see? Running the downstream interceptors later should at least will add a bit of latency, not sure what other implications there might be though.